# weird behavior of json_encode function

Tags: php

I have this normal array name $arr..
and trying to push something on the array using array_push() function.. like `array_push( $arr['alerts_data'], 999 );`
It produces this output:

```
Array
(
    [alerts_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => 169
            [1] => 175
            [2] => 111
            [3] => 48
            [4] => 999
        )

)
```

When i use json_encode I got:

```
{"alerts_data":[169,175,111,48,111,999]}
```

BUT, when I try to unset() something from $arr like:

```
unset( $arr['alerts_data'][4] );// will remove removes the 999
```

and then use the json_encode again, I got this json object

```
{"alerts_data":{"0":169,"1":175,"2":111,"3":48}}
```

What's wrong in here? can you tell? I want to achieve the first encoded json above by using the unset() function.

Comment: I can't confirm with your exact example above (deleting the last numeric element). But if you deleted an array key resulting in a gap in the numbers, you would get an object back.

Comment: Using your exact example, I get `{"alerts_data":[169,175,111,48]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's because the array keys aren't consecutive anymore, so it's treated as an associative array, and PHP associative arrays become JavaScript objects, because JavaScript does not have associative arrays.

Use **[`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)** to cleanly remove elements from the array.

Comment: ... and PHP associative arrays become JavaScript objects, because JavaScript does not have associative arrays.

Comment: there you go, thanks for the answer, didn't know array_splice() is useful in my case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Feel free to edit my answer to add important details to it next time :)

Comment: @KennethPalaganas: It was practically made for cases like this. If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: yeah but it take some time before doing that :) anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a gap in your keys (it goes from 3 to 5), so an object *must* be created for it to be valid.  Two possible solutions:

```
array_splice($arr['alerts_data'], 4, 1);

unset($arr['alerts_data'][4]);
$arr['alerts_data'] = array_values($arr['alerts_data']);
```